# The closure of the orbits of $\mathcal{F} \times \mathcal{F}$

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, rt.representation-theory, geometric-representation-theory

Let $V$ be a finite-dimensional vector space over an algebraically closed field $F$, and $\dim V=d$. Let $G=GL(V)$, $P$ is the parabolic subgroup of $G$. Let $\mathcal{F}$ be the set of all partial flags in $V$.
Consider the diagonal action of $G$ on $\mathcal{F} \times \mathcal{F}$, and $\mathcal{O}$ is an arbitrary orbit of this action.
What is the Zariski closure of $\mathcal{O}$?

Comment: For subgroup $H \subset G$, I think $G$ orbit on $G/H \times G/H$ are the same as $H$ orbits on $G/H$. Because closure of orbits are union of orbits, it should boils down to the usual answer for closure of $B$ orbits in $G/B$, i.e parametrised by the Weyl group, and the closure of $O_w$ is the union of $O_z$ with $z \geq w$. (for parabolic it should work similarly with $W$ replaced by $W_I$).

Comment: @NicolasHemelsoet Thank you for your comment!!! I wonder if there is any reference for me to get more details?

Comment: $P$ orbits in $G/Q$ for $P,Q$ parabolic is well understood (look for "generalised Bruhat decomposition"). It's probably somewhere in Borel's book on linear algebraic groups.

Comment: @NicolasHemelsoet Thank you!